# Fail2Ban rules being circumvented

Tags: nginx, debian, fail2ban

I've been trying to troubleshoot some issues with fail2ban and haven't been able to find any solutions that satisfy the issue. I have enabled the bad-bots filter for nginx and that is working fine. I can verify that fail2ban is updating the iptables: [iptables_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KEr1.png).

But when I look at the access logs for nginx([log_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjhco.png)), it appears: 1.) that the bots are circumventing the rules and 2.) the bantime of 3600 seconds is also not working.

Am I failing to understand something about the way fail2ban is working here? Let me know if there is more that is needed to troubleshoot this....

here is a sample of the logs:

```
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:05 -0400] "POST /app/locale/zh/CN/template/option.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:05 -0400] "POST /dir.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:05 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Connect/plugin.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:05 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Exception.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:05 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Model.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:05 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Model/Config/template.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:06 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:51 -0400] "POST /app/locale/ru/RU/user.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:51 -0400] "POST /app/locale/zh/CN/template/option.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:51 -0400] "POST /dir.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:52 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Connect/plugin.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:52 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Exception.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:52 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Model.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:52 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Model/Config/template.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:11:38:52 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:13:34 -0400] "POST /app/locale/ru/RU/user.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:13:34 -0400] "POST /app/locale/zh/CN/template/option.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:13:34 -0400] "POST /dir.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:13:35 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Connect/plugin.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:13:35 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Exception.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:13:35 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Model.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:13:35 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Model/Config/template.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:13:35 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:26:15 -0400] "POST /app/locale/ru/RU/user.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:26:15 -0400] "POST /app/locale/zh/CN/template/option.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:26:15 -0400] "POST /dir.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:26:16 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Connect/plugin.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:26:16 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Exception.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:26:16 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Model.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:26:16 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Model/Config/template.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
80.87.205.102 - - [03/Aug/2016:12:26:16 -0400] "POST /downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "google.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"
```

and the fail2ban.log:

```
2016-08-03 11:36:42,796 fail2ban.actions[5191]: WARNING [nginx-badbots] Ban 80.87.205.110
2016-08-03 11:36:43,804 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 11:36:44,806 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 11:36:45,807 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 11:38:05,903 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 11:38:06,904 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 11:38:07,906 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 11:38:08,907 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 11:38:51,939 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 11:38:52,940 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 11:38:53,941 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 11:38:54,942 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 11:54:27,001 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 11:54:28,002 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 11:54:29,004 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 11:54:30,005 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 12:07:21,781 fail2ban.actions[5191]: WARNING [nginx-badbots] Ban 162.210.196.98
2016-08-03 12:13:35,224 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 12:13:36,226 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 12:13:37,227 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 12:13:38,229 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 12:22:38,876 fail2ban.actions[5191]: WARNING [nginx-badbots] Unban 80.87.205.102
2016-08-03 12:25:56,126 fail2ban.actions[5191]: WARNING [nginx-badbots] Unban 199.58.86.211
2016-08-03 12:26:16,156 fail2ban.actions[5191]: WARNING [nginx-badbots] Ban 80.87.205.102
2016-08-03 12:26:16,162 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 12:26:17,162 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 12:26:18,164 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.102 already banned
2016-08-03 12:26:19,165 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 12:26:20,167 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 12:26:21,168 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 12:26:22,170 fail2ban.actions[5191]: WARNING [nginx-badbots] Ban 80.87.205.101
2016-08-03 12:26:22,177 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 12:26:23,179 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.101 already banned
2016-08-03 12:26:24,180 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.101 already banned
2016-08-03 12:26:25,182 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.101 already banned
2016-08-03 12:32:06,598 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 12:32:07,600 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 12:32:08,602 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
2016-08-03 12:32:09,603 fail2ban.actions[5191]: INFO    [nginx-badbots] 80.87.205.110 already banned
```

iptables (this was current as of today, but the rules are in the same order):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1097K  433M fail2ban-nginx-badbots  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
1095K  433M fail2ban-nginx-noproxy  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
1092K  433M fail2ban-nginx-http-auth  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
1092K  433M fail2ban-ssh  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
 4050  429K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  !lo    any     loopback/8           anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   15   616 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state NEW icmp echo-request
 1545 92188 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW
14599  766K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http state NEW
27390 1517K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https state NEW
1093K  450M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 2679  183K LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: "
 3620  404K REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: "
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4214 packets, 2981K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-nginx-badbots (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     dslb-178-006-246-231.178.006.pools.vodafone-ip.de  anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   32  1917 REJECT     all  --  any    any     142.54.184.90        anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   24  7139 REJECT     all  --  any    any     80.87.205.103        anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     80.87.205.101        anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   32  1920 REJECT     all  --  any    any     80.87.205.110        anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
1095K  433M RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-nginx-http-auth (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1092K  433M RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-nginx-noproxy (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   17   816 REJECT     all  --  any    any     178-137-87-60-broadband.kyivstar.net  anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
1092K  433M RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1091K  433M RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

and then the jail.local file for fail2ban:

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file.
#
# This file was composed for Debian systems from the original one
# provided now under /usr/share/doc/fail2ban/examples/jail.conf
# for additional examples.
#
# Comments: use '#' for comment lines and ';' for inline comments
#
# To avoid merges during upgrades DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE
# and rather provide your changes in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
#

# The DEFAULT allows a global definition of the options. They can be overridden
# in each jail afterwards.

[DEFAULT]

# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host. Fail2ban will not
# ban a host which matches an address in this list. Several addresses can be
# defined using space separator.
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8 ;naturally my ip address goes here, just omitting here

# External command that will take an tagged arguments to ignore, e.g. ,
# and return true if the IP is to be ignored. False otherwise.
#
# ignorecommand = /path/to/command 
ignorecommand =

# "bantime" is the number of seconds that a host is banned.
bantime  = 3600

# A host is banned if it has generated "maxretry" during the last "findtime"
# seconds.
findtime = 360
maxretry = 3

# "backend" specifies the backend used to get files modification.
# Available options are "pyinotify", "gamin", "polling" and "auto".
# This option can be overridden in each jail as well.
#
# pyinotify: requires pyinotify (a file alteration monitor) to be installed.
#            If pyinotify is not installed, Fail2ban will use auto.
# gamin:     requires Gamin (a file alteration monitor) to be installed.
#            If Gamin is not installed, Fail2ban will use auto.
# polling:   uses a polling algorithm which does not require external libraries.
# auto:      will try to use the following backends, in order:
#            pyinotify, gamin, polling.
backend = auto

# "usedns" specifies if jails should trust hostnames in logs,
#   warn when reverse DNS lookups are performed, or ignore all hostnames in logs
#
# yes:   if a hostname is encountered, a reverse DNS lookup will be performed.
# warn:  if a hostname is encountered, a reverse DNS lookup will be performed,
#        but it will be logged as a warning.
# no:    if a hostname is encountered, will not be used for banning,
#        but it will be logged as info.
usedns = warn

#
# Destination email address used solely for the interpolations in
# jail.{conf,local} configuration files.
destemail = kevin@rocky

#
# Name of the sender for mta actions
sendername = Fail2Ban

# Email address of the sender
sender = fail2ban@localhost

#
# ACTIONS
#

# Default banning action (e.g. iptables, iptables-new,
# iptables-multiport, shorewall, etc) It is used to define
# action_* variables. Can be overridden globally or per
# section within jail.local file
banaction = iptables-allports

# email action. Since 0.8.1 upstream fail2ban uses sendmail
# MTA for the mailing. Change mta configuration parameter to mail
# if you want to revert to conventional 'mail'.
mta = sendmail

# Default protocol
protocol = all

# Specify chain where jumps would need to be added in iptables-* actions
chain = INPUT

#
# Action shortcuts. To be used to define action parameter

# The simplest action to take: ban only
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report to the destemail.
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
              %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report and relevant log lines
# to the destemail.
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
               %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]

# Choose default action.  To change, just override value of 'action' with the
# interpolation to the chosen action shortcut (e.g.  action_mw, action_mwl, etc) in jail.local
# globally (section [DEFAULT]) or per specific section
action = %(action_)s

#
# JAILS
#

####
# other jails present
# just putting the relevant ones here
####
[nginx-http-auth]

enabled = true
filter  = nginx-http-auth
port    = http,https
logpath = /var/log/nginx/error.log

[nginx-noproxy]

enabled = true 
port = http,https
filter = nginx-noproxy
logpath = /var/log/nginx/access.log
maxretry = 2

[nginx-badbots]

enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = nginx-badbots
logpath = /var/log/nginx/access.log
maxretry = 2
```

Comment: Please show your _complete_ firewall rules (you must use `-v`) and the relevant parts of the fail2ban configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've uploaded them